# SimpleTransformers Can't Find GPT_PERSONA_CHAT

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, large-language-model

So I'm using simple transformers and instantiating a pretty basic ConvAi model.

```
from simpletransformers.conv_ai import ConvAIModel
train_args = {
    "num_train_epochs": 50,
    "save_model_every_epoch": False,
}
model = ConvAIModel('gpt','gpt_personachat_cache',use_cuda=True, args=train_args)
model.train_model('data.json')
```

However when I run this I get this error.

```
404 Client Error: Repository Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/gpt_personachat_cache/resolve/main/config.json
```

I might be really bad at searching (xD) but I can't find any solution to this. How would I remedy this?

Comment: Are you following [this tutorial](https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/convAI-minimal-start/)? If so, did you follow the instructions to download the model correctly?

Comment: @myrtlecat (－‸ლ) , thanks a lot!!!